# Should we blacklist the [technical-support] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

24 questions are tagged [technical-support](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/technical-support). Should we get rid of it? Many questions on Super User (every question?) could be considered a form of "technical support". It's a vague term, and doesn't help categorise questions. A few of the questions do relate specifically to the tech support field, but I don't think there are enough good questions to need the tag.

<sub>There are also [43 questions tagged technical support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/technical-support) on SO.</sub>

Comment: yes, totally...

Comment: If somebody needs technical support from a developer/vendor, they're in the wrong place anyway.

Comment: I've edited them, down to 13 questions now which do seem related in some way to technical support. Up to someone else what to do with those!

Comment: Now there are *no* questions under the tag. Guess that makes the answer obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Agreed, it is now burninated (on both sites).

[image: tag burninated]

Comment: +1 for the picture!

Answer (score 2):

All questions that are related to tech support as a field as opposed to questions asked of tech support either have other tags on this site or have other sites, primarily serverfault.com