# request for burnination/synonyms

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tags

In reference to: [Should we blacklist the [technical-support] tag?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3187/should-we-blacklist-the-technical-support-tag)

Shouldn't we also do the same for [customer-support](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/customer-support) and [palm-support](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/palm-support)?

[customer-support](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/customer-support) is general and also a large percentage of the questions under it are closed because they are off topic - the tag itself drives a questions to being off-topic or too localized.

[palm-support](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/palm-support) is much the same, with only one closed entry. I agree that there are legitimate issues that will involve syncing a palm with a computer, but how much will this tag actually aid in categorizing it anymore than simply using the [palm](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/palm) tag? This one could be made a synonym rather than just deleting it, but I don't see it being very useful.

Comment: Can't do more than to agree with this.

Comment: I agree with removing "palm-support" but "customer-support" might be useful as a sort of _red flag_ of tags (although I don't see how this could encourage off-topic questions).  I certainly don't have any problem with seeing the "customer-support" tag removed though.

Comment: All of the customer-support questions were too localised or plain off topic. @ran

Comment: @random:  That seems like a really good justification to me.  (_I saw your answer after submitting my comment._)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both tags have now had all their questions closed and deleted.

After a day the tag clean up system will remove them as tag suggestions.

Unless they're specifically blacklisted, they won't come back again unless a user with at a [reputation of at least 200](https://superuser.com/privileges/create-tags) knowingly tags a question as such.